# Cut string into pieces without breaking words.

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string:

```
$str = 'Hello World, Welcome World, Bye World';
```

I want to cut above string into pieces. Each piece should be of 10 characters. If a word is going to be cut, then move that word to next line.

**For Example:**

```
$output = array();

$output[0] = 'Hello ';
$output[1] = 'World, ';
$output[2] = 'Welcome ';
$output[3] = 'World, Bye'; 
$output[4] = 'World';
```

Is there a shortest way without so many if else and loops.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just split the string on every blank space (" ")? Use `explode(' ', $str);`

Comment: No. There may be 2 or 3 words in 10 characters string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`wordwrap`](https://www.php.net/wordwrap). By default it wraps whole words and does not cut them into pieces.

```
echo wordwrap('Hello World, Welcome World, Bye World', 10);
```

If you want an array, explode afterwards:

```
print_r(explode("\n", wordwrap('Hello World, Welcome World, Bye World', 10)));
```

Comment: Simple and complete solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = 'Hello World, Welcome World, Bye World';
string[] splited = test.Split(' ');
foreach (string str in s.Split(splited))
{
Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

**Note: Its written in C#, I hope it will give you an Idea.**

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly the answer, some similar problem is like this:

You have a long string, you want to break that string into chunks. You prefer not to break words, but words can be broken if word is very long.

```
$string = "Hello I am a sentence but I have verylongwordthat I can split";
```

You will split the words in this sentence if word is very long, like this:

```
$pieces = explode(" ",$string);
$textArray=array();
foreach ($pieces as $p) {
    $textArray= array_merge($textArray, str_split($p, 10));
}
$stringNew=implode(" ",$textArray);
```

output:

```
"Hello I am a sentence but I have verylongwo rdthat I can split"
```